# Как определить на каком устройстве производится код?

Tags: python

Я обожаю писать консольные игры, но в них обязательно очистка консоли, которая производится так:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

И проблема в том, что `cls` работает на Windows, а на телефоне пишется `clear`.
Можно ли сделать как-то определение устройства чтобы автоматически подставлялось либо `clear` (если телефон), либо `cls` (если Windows).

Comment: Да, можно. На этом сайте есть примерно три вопроса, где рассказывается как это сделать.

Comment: Консольные игры на телефоне? Это вообще как?